# groupby with a condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to make groupby depending on a condition which includes two columns, so for example, I have the following dataframe:

```
item   start_date    end_date
A      10/03/2019    31/03/2019
B      10/03/2019    31/03/2019
A      31/03/2019    10/04/2019
B      31/03/2019    10/04/2019
```

and I need to groupbyon items if the end_date equals to the start_date and resulting row should have the start_date of the first row and the end_date of the second row

```
item   start_date    end_date
A      10/03/2019    10/04/2019
B      10/03/2019    10/04/2019
```

An easier example:

```
item   start_date    end_date
A          a             b
A          b             c
A          d             e
A          e             f
```

The wanted result:

```
   item   start_date    end_date
    A          a             c
    A          d             f
```

Comment: How is that a groupby? Sounds more like a filter. Also in your example data not a single row fulfills that condition, so how do you arrive at the expected result? Or did you mean "the same day of the month"?

Comment: For first item `A`, the `end_date` is equal to the `start_date` of the second item `A` so we group by and give the resulting row the `start_date` of the first `A` and the `end_date` of the second `A`.

Comment: I am investigating if this is an answer I need

Comment: @a_guest this is almost a solution, but it does not work in my case because the item could be repeated for various dates intervals, like I updated in the question, and this solution will groupby all of them.

Comment: @a_guest doing more tests, I made sure it works in all cases, this is the solution I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting the DataFrame by values would do. It depends on your aim, too.

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['start_date', 'end_date']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then you can iterate on the sorted rows and apply a function which does what you need. I do not see a mapping solution to this.

Comment: the `groupby` must include the `item` column, I don't think this is 100% correct.

Comment: If you want to iterate you may use groups. I update the answer.

Comment: I will try your solution and give a feedback, thank you!

Comment: Just try sorting, if you need to sort, at least it is what I understood. What do you want to do next?

Comment: grouping by 'start_date', 'end_date' does not really help, please see the update of the question.

Comment: OK, I see. You need sorting here, by `start_date` and `end_date` and then you need to apply a function which iterates on the index of the DataFrame, in order to parse the rows in order.